# Where do I place a FLV file to stream on a local Red5 server?

Tags: streaming, flv, flash, red5, rtmp

I installed the latest Red5 server, but I'm not sure where to put my .flv file to stream it.  There is no "streams" or "ofla" directory like in some tutorials I've found online.

Where do I place the .flv file to stream it?

Comment: have you found the correct way to locate the resource?

Comment: @Kai Chan's answer seemed to work, though I haven't looked at this in awhile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Red5 comes with some demos but they are not installed by default. That is why the directory is not there. Suppose you installed Red5 on yourmachine at /path/to/red5. After starting Red5, open http://yourmachine:5080/installer/ in your browser and install oflaDemo there. After that, you will see a directory named /path/to/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams. That is where the .flv file should go.

Comment: Thanks! Follow-up question: where would I point a resource to find the stream? rmtp://localhost:1935/oflaDemo/streams/avatar.flv doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I'm not able to install the OflaDemo. It stayed for hours with the message: installing oflaDemo-r3989-java6.war... but nothing is happening and the application folder is still empty. Any clue?

Comment: Makram, it may have installed but the alert did not clear. Check your webapps directory and your server log for information.

Comment: In linux: `/usr/lib/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams` In windows: `c:/program files/red5/webapps/oflaDemo/streams` That is where the .flv file should go.

Comment: ofla_demo is in as2. if we write up a basic as3 app to connect to it we can establish the connection. pointing to the video fla resource does not work i.e ns.play("rmtp://localhost/oflaDemo/streams/avatar.flv ") does not work. what is the correct way to give the url for it to work??