# purchased a Flash website for my radio station

Tags: flash, actionscript, streaming, audio-streaming, internet-radio

I've purchased a Flash website for my radio station www.SSSVibez.com.
The flash website has an mp3 playing in the background when you open it. The code looks as such:

```
var mysound = new Sound();

_root.mysound.onLoad = function (loadedOK)

 { if(loadedOK)

 {_root.mysound.start(0,9999);}

}
_root.mysound.loadSound("music.mp3", false);
```

Which works fine but I want my radio stream to play instead of an MP3 file 
and I don't know how to go about it (it's been a while since I used Actionscript. Note it's built on Actionscript 2.0.

Comment: you need to play RTMP stream in flash, which is possible, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15967523/how-can-i-play-a-rtmp-video-through-netconnection-and-netstream

Comment: This Template is  Actionscript 2.0 and example is 3.0  i only need audio so is it still videoURL?

Answer (score 0):

> I've purchased a Flash website for my radio station

I hate to tell you this, but Flash is disappearing rapidly.  If you can get your money back, I'd recommend doing so.

> This Template is Actionscript 2.0

In ActionScript 2.0, it isn't possible to have an HTTP stream without a memory leak of sorts.  Listeners that tune-in for more than a few hours are likely to run into this.

> I want my radio stream to play instead of an MP3 file

Simply put in the URL of the stream instead of the URL of the MP3 file.

If you're playing a stream from a SHOUTcast server, you'll need to use a semicolon `;` at the end of the URL.  For example, if your server is running at `http://stream.example.com:8000/`, use the stream URL `http://stream.example.com:8000/;`.  This gets around a quirk of SHOUTcast servers where they return the admin page rather than the stream URL for user agents containing "Mozilla".  Other servers don't suffer from this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your Response unfortunately  Simply putting in the URL of the stream instead of the URL of the MP3 file this MP3 is held local no URL . ive tried the semi colon also

Comment: @DjTech What's the URL of your stream?

Comment: @DjTech Alright, if you use `_root.mysound.loadSound("http://198.50.158.92:8888/;", true)`, it should work just fine.  Don't forget to use `true` for streaming mode.